# Cloud firestore WhereIn method not working in .Net

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am using `google.cloud.firestore` package in `.net core` and I want to query the documents that have a specific field value existing in a provided list of values (like the `IN` command in sql). I came across the `WhereIn` method but I keep getting an exception. I have been trying for the last few hours but no success!
Here is the code:

```
   public async Task<List<Document>> GetListByAccountRef(List<string> accountRefs)
    {
        var docRef = _Firestore.Collection("documents").WhereIn("AccountRef", accountRefs);
        var docsQuery = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        var docs = docsQuery.Select(d => d.ConvertTo<Document>()).ToList();
        return docs;
    }
```

I get an exception on the second line:
`var docsQuery = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();`

This is the error message:

```
Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Unknown FieldFilter operator.")
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Grpc.Core.Internal.ClientResponseStream`2.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync_>d__174`1.MoveNext() in 
D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\ForEach.cs:line 141
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.<GetSnapshotAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Docer.DAL.Repositories.DocumentRepository.<GetListByAccountRef>d__7.MoveNext() in E:\Docer\webapp- 
FireStore-Branch\Docer.DAL\Repositories\Document\DocumentRepository.cs:line 84
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Docer.BLL.Doc.DocumentBusiness.<GetUserDocuments>d__10.MoveNext() in E:\Docer\webapp-FireStore- 
Branch\Docer.BLL.Doc\Document\DocumentBusiness.cs:line 84
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's distinctly surprising. I've filed https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/4543 - I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you so much Jon!

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system. I've added a sample program in the issue - could you try that and let me know whether it works for you? (It's probably worth doing all the remaining back-and-forth on the issue; we can add an answer here when we know what's going on.)

Comment: As noted in the issue, it looks like this is a matter of running against an old emulator.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jon, I will check it.

Comment: @JonSkeet The problem is gone after updating the emulator. Tnx.

Comment: Excellent. I would suggest either deleting this question (if you think others are unlikely to see the same problem) or adding an answer explaining what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jon, the problem appeared to be from the old version of the firestore emulator that I was using. After updating the emulator, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  You can follow the tutorial (https://pieterdlinde.medium.com/netcore-and-cloud-firestore-94628943eb3c)

```
                List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>()
                {
                    new Cities()
                    {
                        CityName="tests"
                    }
                };
                Query employeeQuery = fireStoreDb.Collection(nameof(Employee)).WhereIn("City", cities);
                QuerySnapshot employeeQuerySnapshot = await employeeQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
```